# indexing cursor adapter by date

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-cursoradapter, android-cursor, android-date

I have a cursor adapter that reads from sqlite database in my application and fills the data in a listview, in the same activity I have a date slider, whenever the user scrolls the date slider the listview should scroll to the list item that is mapped to that date, how can I map the cursor with the selected date ?!

I have a time stamp field in the database, also not all dates exist in the database. and a date exist only once.

how can I implement a solution taking into consideration memory foot print ?
the only solution I got is to save all the dates with their cursor positions in an array, but I have around 700 date and I believe its not efficient.

Comment: first sort your cursor by that date, second when you have your data sorted ypu can use binary search algorithm